# RHEL7 Cron entry gives ambiguous redirect error?

Tags: shell-script, rhel, cron

We have a crontab entry that ends up sending an ambiguous redirect error. Pretty sure it's the command to read the date, but don't know how to fix. Are there other solutions?

/bin/sh redirects to /bin/bash

```
 /opt/startup-shutdown/startup.instances Other > /tmp/`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`-cron.log 2>&1
```

gives:

```
/bin/sh: 1  
: ambiguous redirect
```

Comment: What shell is `/bin/sh`? Dies it support backticks? Did you try `$()`?

Comment: edited question, yes, no

Comment: Backticks should be standard, and that `date` command should just output a pile of numbers, which shouldn't be problematic for the redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crontab uses **%** for a special purpose:

> The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline **or  %
> character**, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the  shell  specified  in
> the SHELL variable of the crontab file.  Percent-signs (%) in the
> command, unless escaped with backslash (),  will  be  changed  into
> newline  characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to
> the command as standard input.

If you put a date command into the crontab, **every %** must be quoted with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a carriage return issue.

That's the error Bash gives e.g. if the word to the right of a redirection operator expands to multiple fields E.g. as in `echo > *` gives `bash: *: ambiguous redirect`.

Here, it mentions `1` and there's a line break after. I can get a similar error with an input that has `2>&1<CR><LF>`, e.g.:

```
$ printf 'echo foo 2>&1\r\n' |bash
: ambiguous redirect
```

There, the CR moves the cursor to the start of the line, so whatever comes after writes over the first part. Here with the CR visible:

```
$ printf 'echo foo 2>&1\r\n' |bash 2>&1|cat -A
bash: line 1: 1^M: ambiguous redirect$
```

I don't know why in your case the CR would be printed as a regular line break, it's probably a terminal setting.

Check if your file came from Windows and run it through `dos2unix` or `sed -i 's/\r//'` or whatever. A search for "carriage return" should bring some hits.